# How to shift nomenclature list toward right?

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature, nomencl

The list of nomenclatures is using the same margin as the document. How can I shift it toward slightly right?
Currently, It looks like this:

[image]

Using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature[03]{$2a$}{Number}
\nomenclature[01]{$aa$}{Lower Case Letter}
\nomenclature[02]{$\alpha$}{Greek Character}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

I want this aa, a, 2a to shift slightly right, not aligned to the heading "Nomenclature". How to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would be a lot easier to answer if had an idea of how you produced that output.

Comment: @campa Just edited this. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\hspace*{1.0em}#1}
```

which yields:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{\hspace*{1.0em}#1}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature[03]{$2a$}{Number}
\nomenclature[01]{$aa$}{Lower Case Letter}
\nomenclature[02]{$\alpha$}{Greek Character}

\printnomenclature[2.0cm]

\end{document}
```